# ActivityIndicator with text Xamarin.Forms cross platform

Tags: cross-platform, xamarin.forms, activity-indicator

Is there anything like the ActivityIndicator that allows you to add text? Or would I need to write some sort of custom renderer class to go along with it?

[image: ActivityIndicator with text]

Edit: Added picture.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Why not put it in a `StackLayout` together with a `Label`?

Comment: I added a picture. I didn't think of a `StackLayout` with a `Label`... something like that might work!

Comment: Something like that can be done with Acr.UserDialogs indeed like noted by Egor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to suggest you to use [Acr.UserDialogs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Acr.UserDialogs/). `ShowLoading` for example.

Comment: Awesome! I'm using something else for toasts already also but ACR might be a better choice for that also.It's too bad they don't have screen shot examples of what everything looks like! Oh well! I'll Accept your answer in a few minutes when it lets me, Thanks again